# In which AndroidX library is the androidx.test.annotation package located?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, androidx-test

Simple question:

How can I use the androidx.test.annotation package? In which AndroidX library is it located? I'm specifically looking to use [androidx.test.annotation.UiThreadTest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/annotation/UiThreadTest). This annotation is the continuation of android.support.test.annotation.UiThreadTest from pre-AndroidX times.

This package is not listed on the [AndroidX Migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) page. Is it included in another library? If so, which one? I cannot find it for the life of me. Package search within the IDE comes up with nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in `androidx.test:rules`:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
```